# how do I fix my variables so they evaluate as equal?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, hashlib

I have two variables that hold the same data when I input "hi". but my if statement evaluates it as false. I dont know why this happening.

```
#modules
import hashlib as hl
import multiprocessing as mp
import playsound as ps
from os import system


#functions

def password():
    file = open("crack.md5", "r")
    cont = file.read()
    file.close()

    
    for i in range(5):
        system('cls')
        user_in = str(input("Please input user password>> "))
        hashed = hl.md5(user_in.encode())
        hash_dig = hashed.hexdigest()
        
        
        print(hash_dig)
        print(cont)
        
        
        if hash_dig == cont:
            main(False)
        else:
            input("сука блять, ты не русский. это не верный\nPress enter to continue")
        if i == 4:
            input("To many attempts cyka blyat you will now be sent to gulag, press enter")
            exit()          
    


    
def main(locked):
    if locked == True:
        password()
    while True:
        print("yay you got it correct")
        
password()
```

why is it doing this? how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the types for ```hash_dig``` and ```cont```? Also, adding the output might make it easier to debug.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I fixed it, the data had white spaces in it. I used cont.strip()